# google geolocation api issue

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-geolocation

I have issue with google geo location api. it is returning wrong latitude & longitude of my current position. when i first time integrated it was returning correct but now returning wrong. please have look my below javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var apiGeolocationSuccess = function (position) {
                alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);

            };

            var tryAPIGeolocation = function () {
                jQuery.post("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", function (success) {
                    apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
                })
                        .fail(function (err) {
                            alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n" + err);
                        });
            };

            var browserGeolocationSuccess = function (position) {
                //alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);

            };

            var browserGeolocationFail = function (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        //alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
                        if (error.TIMEOUT)
                        {
                            tryAPIGeolocation();
                        }

                        break;
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        if (error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
                            tryAPIGeolocation();
                        }
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
                        break;
                }
            };
            var tryGeolocation = function () {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                            browserGeolocationSuccess,
                            browserGeolocationFail,
                            {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
                }
            };

            tryAPIGeolocation();
```

if i run above code i am getting this value (latitude : 23.0401214) (longitude : 72.5163579) but this is wrong. it returns ahemdabad city lat & long.

correct value it should be : 22.3039 , 70.8022

please have a look with my issue.

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 Geolocation provided by browser may detect client geographical location using GPS device (high accuracy) or cellular tower triangulation (medium accuracy).

By looking into your code, your application tries to detect user geographical location as early as possible which is very likely using IP address.

IP address to location mapping may not accurate depending on your user Internet service provider.

User device may be allocated IP address which its geographical location registered very differently from user's actual geographical location.

So it is expected behavior. Until user agree to give you consent on sharing their geolocation, that is best effort you can do.

Comment: yes but html 5 geolocation service required https secure domain not working for http only.

Comment: ok is there not any other ways we can get exact location of user except html5 technique ?

Comment: Yes there is. Let user point on the map their exact location.

Comment: you mean user need to mark their exact location on map first right ? or you are telling some other things ?

Comment: Yes, you just display what ever google geolocation gives you. And tell user that if its not accurate then they can point their own location on the map.